# In meteor, how to wait for subscriptions and access them in template `rendered` function?

Tags: meteor, flow-router

Im using the `FlowRouter` in my app and new to Meteor. I have subscribed to my collection like this :

```
Template.PanelEditAbout.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
        self.subscribe('pages', 'about');
    });
});
```

Im trying to use the subscription in the `rendered` function but it's not working :

```
Template.PanelEditAbout.rendered = function() {
    page = Pages.findOne({
        slug: 'about'
    });
}
```

If im correct, I have to wait for the subscription to be available. How can I do this? I also need to add a loading msg (or a spinner) while it's getting ready. I know how to do this in IronRouter but not with the FlowRouter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't ever subscribe in `onRendered`, first off. Try the below:

```
Template.PanelEditAbout.onCreated(function() {
  this.subscribe('pages', 'about');
});

Template.PanelEditAbout.onRendered(function() {
  let page = {};

  this.autorun(() => {
    if (this.subscriptionsReady()) {
      console.log('subs ready');
      page = Pages.findOne({
        slug: 'about'
      });
    }

    console.log(page);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onReady during your subscribtion to page if it is the name of your publication.

```
Template.PanelEditAbout.rendered = function() {
  Meteor.subscribe("page", Yourslug,{
    onReady: function () { console.log("onReady And the Itemns actually Arrive",     arguments); },
    onError: function () { console.log("onError", arguments); }
  });
};
```

the console log is just an exemple.

Comment: If you speak about loading message like a real time tchat I think you have to use reactivars and helpers.

Comment: Everything is working but when I add a loading msg, the CKEDITOR function can't find the text area

Comment: Ok so, in the other answer he is right do the suscription and wait in the onCreated, and use an helper to format your data  and next you put in your html page <textarea>{{#nameOfYourHelper}}</textarea>. I m not totally sure, but try it.

Comment: Amazing! This was exactly what I needed to do a recursive subscription model. I had to ensure that data A was available, before loading data B and C, and finally D which relied on C.